# Android Augmented Reality

Tags: android, augmented-reality, flex4.5, flartoolkit

I am planning to develop augmented reality on android platform.Flash 4.5 SDK now enables us to develop applications now on mobile platform. I wanted to ask if its possible to develop AR app on mobile using Flar Manager,papervision??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if FLAR has AIR support (I think so because it is written in AS3) but nevertheless I'd reckon it would be very slow. Even on desktops FLARs speed is nothing compared to AR apps written in C++. Also on mobile the AIR app will run inside its own sandbox/player which won't be good for performance.

However, the best way of telling it will do or not would be by testing it.